# Unsupported operand type

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program where I can input a username and it will use person distance to find the nearest person.

I keep running into these errors, more  specifically the operand error. How do I remedy this?

The Traceback is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
    line 60, in <module> pprint(nearest_neighbor("Ricky", users))    
    line 52, in nearest_neighbor (pearson(ratings[username], ratings[other_user]),     
    line 22, in pearson square_sum1 = sum(pow(ratingsUser1.values(),2))    
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'dict_values' and 'int'
```

And here's my code:

```
users = {"Ricky": {"Bob Seger": 4.75, "CCR": 4.5, "Beatles": 5, "The Who": 4.25, "Taylor Swift": 4},
     "Meg": {"Bob Seger": 4, "CCR": 3, "Beatles": 5, "The Who": 2, "Taylor Swift": 1},
     "Jake": {"Bob Seger": 4, "CCR": 3, "Beatles": 5, "The Who": 3, "Taylor Swift": 3}
     }

def pearson(ratingsUser1, ratingsUser2):


# Summation over all attributes for both objects
sum_ratingsUser1 = sum(ratingsUser1.values())
sum_ratingsUser2 = sum(ratingsUser2.values())

# Sum the squares
square_sum1 = sum(pow(ratingsUser1.values(),2))
square_sum2 = sum(pow(ratingsUser2.values(),2))

# Add up the products
product = sum([ratingsUser1.values*ratingsUser2.values])

#Calculate Pearson Correlation score
numerator = product - (sum_ratingsUser1*sum_ratingsUser2/len(ratingsUser1))
denominator = ((square_sum1 - pow(sum_ratingsUser1,2)/len(ratingsUser1)) * (square_sum2 -
    pow(sum_ratingsUser2,2)/len(ratingsUser1))) ** 0.5

# Can"t have division by 0
if denominator == 0:
    return 0

result = numerator/denominator
return result
# Compute the Summation

# Compute the numerator

# Compute the denominator


def nearest_neighbor(username, ratings):
distances = []

for other_user in ratings:
    if other_user != username:
        distances.append(
            (pearson(ratings[username], ratings[other_user]), other_user)
        )
distances.sort()

return distances

from pprint import pprint

pprint(nearest_neighbor("Ricky", users))
```

Comment: First, you should indent your code properly. Second, do you want to raise all values to a power and then get the sum of the results or sum all the values and then raise the result to a power?

`pow(sum(some_dictionary.values()),2)` # works
`sum(pow(some_dictionary.values()),2)` # does not work. Requires an iteration, for loop, lamba function, map, etc. to apply operation to each element in `dict_values`. You can't do `pow()` on multiple elements like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Your code had a few issues...

1. In the line where you write `square_sum1 = sum(pow(ratingsUser1.values(),2))` you are trying to take a sum of dictionary values, in this case, it's better to loop through them via for loop.
2. After trying to run after fixing that error I found another. In the line where you write `product = sum([ratingsUser1.values*ratingsUser2.values])` you are again trying to take the sum of dictionary values multiplied together, and even if you COULD do that you missed `()`'s at the end of `values`.

---

```
from pprint import pprint

users = {"Ricky": {"Bob Seger": 4.75, "CCR": 4.5, "Beatles": 5, "The Who": 4.25, "Taylor Swift": 4},
     "Meg": {"Bob Seger": 4, "CCR": 3, "Beatles": 5, "The Who": 2, "Taylor Swift": 1},
     "Jake": {"Bob Seger": 4, "CCR": 3, "Beatles": 5, "The Who": 3, "Taylor Swift": 3}
     }

def pearson(ratingsUser1, ratingsUser2):



    # Summation over all attributes for both objects
    sum_ratingsUser1 = sum(ratingsUser1.values())
    sum_ratingsUser2 = sum(ratingsUser2.values())

    # Sum the squares
    square_sum1 = 0
    square_sum2 = 0
    for value in ratingsUser1.values():
        square_sum1 += pow(value, 2)
    for value in ratingsUser2.values():
        square_sum2 += pow(value, 2)


    # Add up the products
    product = sum_ratingsUser1 * sum_ratingsUser2

    #Calculate Pearson Correlation score
    numerator = product - (sum_ratingsUser1*sum_ratingsUser2/len(ratingsUser1))
    denominator = ((square_sum1 - pow(sum_ratingsUser1,2)/len(ratingsUser1)) * (square_sum2 -
        pow(sum_ratingsUser2,2)/len(ratingsUser1))) ** 0.5

    # Can"t have division by 0
    if denominator == 0:
        return 0

    result = numerator/denominator
    return result
# Compute the Summation

# Compute the numerator

# Compute the denominator


def nearest_neighbor(username, ratings):
    distances = []

    for other_user in ratings:
        if other_user != username:
            distances.append(
                (pearson(ratings[username], ratings[other_user]), other_user)
            )
    distances.sort()

    return distances



pprint(nearest_neighbor("Ricky", users))
```

Happy programming!
Signal

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [pow](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow) with dict/list

```
from pprint import pprint

users = {"Ricky": {"Bob Seger": 4.75, "CCR": 4.5, "Beatles": 5, "The Who": 4.25, "Taylor Swift": 4},
     "Meg": {"Bob Seger": 4, "CCR": 3, "Beatles": 5, "The Who": 2, "Taylor Swift": 1},
     "Jake": {"Bob Seger": 4, "CCR": 3, "Beatles": 5, "The Who": 3, "Taylor Swift": 3}
     }


def pearson(ratingsUser1, ratingsUser2):
    # Summation over all attributes for both objects
    sum_ratingsUser1 = sum(ratingsUser1.values())
    sum_ratingsUser2 = sum(ratingsUser2.values())
    # Sum the squares
    square_sum1 = sum(base ** 2 for base in ratingsUser1.values())
    square_sum2 = sum(base ** 2 for base in ratingsUser2.values())
    # Add up the products
    product = sum_ratingsUser1 * sum_ratingsUser2


    try:
        # Can"t have division by 0
        #Calculate Pearson Correlation score
        numerator = product - (sum_ratingsUser1*sum_ratingsUser2 / len(ratingsUser1))
        denominator = (
                          (square_sum1 - pow(sum_ratingsUser1, 2)/len(ratingsUser1)) *
                          (square_sum2 - pow(sum_ratingsUser2, 2)/len(ratingsUser1))) ** 0.5

        return numerator/denominator
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

# Compute the Summation
# Compute the numerator
# Compute the denominator

 def nearest_neighbor(username, ratings):    
    distances = [(pearson(ratings[username], ratings[other_user]), other_user) for other_user in ratings if other_user != username and username in ratings ]
    distances.sort()
    return distances




pprint(nearest_neighbor("Ricky", users))
```